# PyOrient client.command("SELECT X FROM Protein") seems to always return the internal ID of the record (Studio returns the property)

Tags: python, sql, graph-databases, orientdb3.0

I am trying to develop python programs to set up a multi-omics graph database in OrientDB, starting with the gene-transcript-protein relations from Ensembl.
A completely unexpected problem I have run into is that the python interface (pyorient/pyorientdb),for queries like client.command("SELECT uID FROM Protein") seems to always return the internal ID of the record, not the property (iUD) I am asking for, as you would expect (and Studio does).
This is not a special problem with uID (might be consider an index, triggering a special behaviour), but seems to happen with any property.
e.g.

loadedProteinUIDs=client.command("select uID from Protein LIMIT 5")
print(loadedProteinUIDs)
loadedProteinXIDs=client.command("select xID from Protein LIMIT 5")
print(loadedProteinXIDs)
loadedProteinXXXs=client.command("select xxx from Protein LIMIT 5")
print(loadedProteinXXXs)
...
[<pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551a30>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a5517f0>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551a90>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551940>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a5512b0>]
[<pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551a30>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a5517f0>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551a90>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551940>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a5512b0>]
[<pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551fa0>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551b50>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551d30>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14a551d90>, <pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x14ae01040>]

Studio seems to go through the REST interface, giving the correct result. I have, as yet, no idea, why the python interface does not give the  same results.
Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pyorient driver for OrientDB returns a list of OrientRecord objects when you query the database using `client.command()` or `client.query()`. In order to access the data you are looking for, you need to call the `oRecordData` property of these objects:

```py
import pyorient

client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)
client.set_session_token(True)  # set true to enable the token based auth
client.db_open("GratefulDeadConcerts", "admin", "admin")

song_name_raw = client.query("SELECT count(*) FROM V")
print(song_name_raw)  # [<pyorientdb.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x000001F9F6C37DC0>]

print(song_name_raw[0].oRecordData)  # {'count': 1234}
```